# Multiple Counts Grouped by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like:

```
ConnectDate ErrorCode  
2015-01-01  NULL  
2015-01-01  A  
2015-01-01  A  
2015-01-01  B  
2015-01-02  B
```

On **MySQL**, how would I get a count of each `ErrorCode` by day like:

```
Date        ErrorA  ErrorB  
2015-01-01  2       1  
2015-01-02  0       1
```

Comment: Please can you give us the structure of your table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select connectdate, sum(errorcode = 'A') as ErrorA, sum(errorcode = 'B') as ErrorB
from table t
group by connectdate;
```